# Is there a way to run Selenium tests on a remote host?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I would like to run the following setup:

- on `host_1`, execute some Selenium tests
- on `host_2`, run Firefox

(On `host_1` there would be a Jenkins instance running the tests and `host_2` would be a Docker container running on `host_1`, and Firefox would run headless, using xvfb - but this shouldn't be relevant for the question)

To run on the same host, I would just do:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/to/geckodriver");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com/");
driver.quit();
```

But I would like the Selenium tests to use the Firefox instance on the other host. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you looked into Selenium Grid? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Selenium Grid.
Check this [link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) for detailed documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium Standalone Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

The **Selenium Server** is needed in order to run **Remote Selenium WebDriver**.